Data not showing on form - Datagridview problem
I am working on a project in C#, but I only have knowledge of Java.
In my project, I have a class that structures my database, but when I call the form that displays the database data, the form appears with empty rows.
I have already tried making several changes to both the class and the form, but nothing works.
The form screen either appears empty or does not display the data.
The comments are my Java attempt to carry out the project.
I apologize for some Portuguese text, but I believe the logic of each one is understandable regardless of the language.
Class:

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;

namespace PMOA
{
public class PMOA
{
// Construtor
public PMOA(double kmDesenvolvido, double pn, double pressaoProjeto, double pth, double ft, double pinteg)
{
KmDesenvolvido = kmDesenvolvido;
Pn = pn;
if (pressaoProjeto \> pn)
{
throw new ArgumentException("A Pressão do Projeto (pressaoProejeto) deve menor ou igual a Pressão Nominal (pn)", nameof(PressaoProjeto));
}
else
{
PressaoProjeto = pressaoProjeto;
}

            double pthFt = (pth / ft);
            if (pthFt > pressaoProjeto)
            {
                throw new ArgumentException("Pressão Hidrostática/Fator de segurança (pthFt) deve menor que a Pressão do Projeto (pressaoProjeto)", nameof(pthFt));
            }
            else
            {
                PthFt = pthFt;
            }
    
            if (pinteg > pressaoProjeto)
            {
                throw new ArgumentException("Pressão Máxima do Sistema (Pinteg) deve menor que a Pressão do Projeto (pressaoProjeto)", nameof(Pinteg));
            }
            else
            {
                Pinteg = pinteg;
            }
    
            ValorPMOA = Math.Min(Math.Min(Pn, PressaoProjeto), Math.Min(PthFt, Pinteg));
        }
    
        public PMOA(double kmDesenvolvido, double pn, double pressaoProjeto, double pthFt, double pinteg)
        {
            KmDesenvolvido = kmDesenvolvido;
            Pn = pn;
            if (pressaoProjeto > pn)
            {
                throw new ArgumentException("A Pressão do Projeto (pressaoProejeto) deve menor ou igual a Pressão Nominal (pn)", nameof(PressaoProjeto));
            }
            else
            {
                PressaoProjeto = pressaoProjeto;
            }
    
            if (pthFt > pressaoProjeto)
            {
                throw new ArgumentException("Pressão Hidrostática/Fator de segurança (pthFt) deve menor que a Pressão do Projeto (pressaoProjeto)", nameof(pthFt));
            }
            else
            {
                PthFt = pthFt;
            }
    
            if (pinteg > pressaoProjeto)
            {
                throw new ArgumentException("Pressão Máxima do Sistema (Pinteg) deve menor que a Pressão do Projeto (pressaoProjeto)", nameof(Pinteg));
            }
            else
            {
                Pinteg = pinteg;
            }
    
            ValorPMOA = Math.Min(Math.Min(Pn, PressaoProjeto), Math.Min(PthFt, Pinteg));
        }
    
        public PMOA() { }
    
        // Propriedades
        private double KmDesenvolvido { get; set; }
        private double Pn { get; set; }
        private double PressaoProjeto { get; set; }
        private double PthFt { get; set; }
        private double Pinteg { get; set; }
        private double ValorPMOA { get; set; }
    }

}

Form:

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace PMOA
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
List\<PMOA\> listaPMOAs;
public Form1()
{
InitializeComponent();

            listaPMOAs = new List<PMOA>
            {
                new PMOA(0, 103.15, 98.5, 98.0, 98.0),
                new PMOA(0.014, 103.22, 98.5, 98.0, 98.0),
                new PMOA(0.0263, 103.35, 98.8, 98.7, 98.78),
                new PMOA(0.0384, 103.44, 98.9, 98.5, 98.5),
                new PMOA(0.0504, 103.54, 103.54, 103.0, 103.0),
                new PMOA(0.3099, 105.41, 101.0, 97, 98.27)
            };
    
            // Configurar DataSource
            dataGridView1.DataSource = listaPMOAs;
        }
    }

}

Form Designer:

...
#region Windows Form Designer generated code

        /// <summary>
        /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
        /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
        /// </summary>
        private void InitializeComponent()
        {
            this.components = new System.ComponentModel.Container();
            System.ComponentModel.ComponentResourceManager resources = new System.ComponentModel.ComponentResourceManager(typeof(Form1));
            this.dataGridView1 = new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView();
            this.KmDesenvolvido = new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
            this.Pn = new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
            this.PressaoProjeto = new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
            this.PthFt = new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
            this.Pintegr = new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
            this.PMOA = new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
            this.grafico = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
            this.tabelaEstatistica = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
            this.carregarXML = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
            this.salvaXML = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
            this.exportarExcel = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
            ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.dataGridView1)).BeginInit();
            this.SuspendLayout();
            // 
            // dataGridView1
            // 
            this.dataGridView1.BackgroundColor = System.Drawing.SystemColors.InactiveBorder;
            this.dataGridView1.ColumnHeadersHeightSizeMode = System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewColumnHeadersHeightSizeMode.AutoSize;
            this.dataGridView1.Columns.AddRange(new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewColumn[] {
            this.KmDesenvolvido,
            this.Pn,
            this.PressaoProjeto,
            this.PthFt,
            this.Pintegr,
            this.PMOA});
            this.dataGridView1.GridColor = System.Drawing.SystemColors.ActiveCaptionText;
            resources.ApplyResources(this.dataGridView1, "dataGridView1");
            this.dataGridView1.Name = "dataGridView1";
            this.dataGridView1.UseWaitCursor = true;
            // 
            // KmDesenvolvido
            // 
            this.KmDesenvolvido.AutoSizeMode = System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.ColumnHeader;
            resources.ApplyResources(this.KmDesenvolvido, "KmDesenvolvido");
            this.KmDesenvolvido.Name = "KmDesenvolvido";
            // 
            // Pn
            // 
            this.Pn.AutoSizeMode = System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.ColumnHeader;
            resources.ApplyResources(this.Pn, "Pn");
            this.Pn.Name = "Pn";
            // 
            // PressaoProjeto
            // 
            this.PressaoProjeto.AutoSizeMode = System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.ColumnHeader;
            resources.ApplyResources(this.PressaoProjeto, "PressaoProjeto");
            this.PressaoProjeto.Name = "PressaoProjeto";
            // 
            // PthFt
            // 
            this.PthFt.AutoSizeMode = System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.ColumnHeader;
            resources.ApplyResources(this.PthFt, "PthFt");
            this.PthFt.Name = "PthFt";
            // 
            // Pintegr
            // 
            this.Pintegr.AutoSizeMode = System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.ColumnHeader;
            resources.ApplyResources(this.Pintegr, "Pintegr");
            this.Pintegr.Name = "Pintegr";
            // 
            // PMOA
            // 
            this.PMOA.AutoSizeMode = System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.ColumnHeader;
            resources.ApplyResources(this.PMOA, "PMOA");
            this.PMOA.Name = "PMOA";
            // 
            // Form1
            // 
            resources.ApplyResources(this, "$this");
            this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
            this.Controls.Add(this.dataGridView1);
            this.Name = "Form1";
            ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.dataGridView1)).EndInit();
            this.ResumeLayout(false);
        }
    
        #endregion
    
        private System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView dataGridView1;
        private System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn KmDesenvolvido;
        private System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn Pn;
        private System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn PressaoProjeto;
        private System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn PthFt;
        private System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn Pintegr;
        private System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn PMOA;
    }

}



The properties in your model PMOA must be public properties.

Might be better to use a binding list or a strongly typed datatable
